# set button Visible/invisible in Textwatcher in android

Tags: android, visible, textwatcher, invisible

i want to show a hidden button when user put any word on Edittext.
im already try this method :

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

this is my code in TextWatcher :

```
final EditText txtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CategoryCustomAdapter adapter2 =
                new CategoryCustomAdapter(showCategoryListActivity.this,
                        DatabaseHelper.getCategories(
                                showCategoryListActivity.this,s.toString()));
        ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstCategorylist)).setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

every thing work fine except this line :

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

i'm sure you can help me out.
**ps: API 19 Nexus 4 android 4.4.2**

Comment: can you assign your button before ? Personnally i will put the code in afterTextChanged. Then you can put btnClear.setvisibility(count > 0 ? VISIBLE : GONE );

Comment: i'm afraid that's not the solution . but i did every thing you said and nothing happened.(force close on the beginning)

Comment: Can you post the logcat logs here if you are getting a force close ?
How can you say everything works fine except that line ?
The only reason i think of is that you are wrong with your "R.id.btnClear" name.

Comment: @ManishKhot - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pedram.database/com.example.pedram.database.showCategoryListActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness

Answer (score 0):

Declare you variable earlier like this -in Oncreate.

```
Button howtoButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.howtobutton);
```

Than use it like this

```
howtoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
howtoButton.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: You need to determine if your using ImageButton or regular Button those are different that is why you get error. One is Cast ImageButton buttonname = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ofbutton) and other is Button without the Image part. Follow what is in your xml.@PedramHassas

Answer (score 0):

finally figure it out.  
logs say :

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompat**ImageButton** cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.**Button**

change this on onCreate():

```
final Button btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
```

to this :

```
final ImageButton btnClear = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
```

i dont know why but i use some background for my Button and some how it turns to **ImageButton** and `btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`works fine in    `public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)`

```
public class showCategoryListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_category_list);

        final ListView lstCategory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstCategorylist);
        final ImageButton btnClear = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        final EditText txtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);

        CategoryCustomAdapter adapter =
                new CategoryCustomAdapter(this,DatabaseHelper.getCategories(
                        this,((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSearch)).getText().toString()));
        lstCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

        txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                CategoryCustomAdapter adapter2 =
                        new CategoryCustomAdapter(showCategoryListActivity.this,
                                DatabaseHelper.getCategories(
                                        showCategoryListActivity.this,s.toString()));
                ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstCategorylist)).setAdapter(adapter2);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        txtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    CategoryCustomAdapter adapter = new CategoryCustomAdapter(
                            showCategoryListActivity.this,
                            DatabaseHelper.getCategories(
                                    showCategoryListActivity.this,
                                    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSearch)).getText().toString()));
                    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstCategorylist)).setAdapter(adapter);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            });
    }


    public void btn_clear_clicked(View view) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSearch)).setText("");
        CategoryCustomAdapter adapter = new CategoryCustomAdapter(
                showCategoryListActivity.this,
                DatabaseHelper.getCategories(
                        showCategoryListActivity.this,
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSearch)).getText().toString()
                )
        );
        ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstCategorylist)).setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

XML for Button :

```html
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="btn_clear_clicked (showCategoryListActivity)"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:elevation="0dp" />
```

**Sorry for my carelessness**

Comment: A good start to post an Answer once you have resolved the issue. A couple of other issues with your code base.
1. Never create a new adapter inside the listner. Create a method that will refresh the data that Adapter uses.
2. Set Adapter to the ListView outside the click listener. 
3. Only the code initialization needs to happen in OnCreate, for rest of the stuff use onStart.